# Yii Displaying Image dynamically dependent on dropdown

Tags: image, yii

I'm trying to display an image but is dependent on a dropdown list in Yii. I can get the image from the database and display it, but how to do it dynamically depending on the choice from the dropdown?

Comment: Not enough information, but you will need to either preload *all* images or make an AJAX call each time the dropdown is changed.

Comment: sorry, i need it to make an ajax call each time the dropdown is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/creating-a-dependent-dropdown#hh0 but, let me show you how to do it.

First all all, we need a div where the image will be displayed; I'll create one whose id will be 'img'. Then, the ajax request is specified inside the dropdownlist() as follows:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'attribue'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'attribute',
array(/*The options in the DropDownList*/),
array(
          'ajax'=>array(
             'type'=>'POST',
             'url'=>CController::createUrl('YourController/actionWhichEchoesTheImage'),
             'update'=>'#img',
))); 
?>

<div id="img">   // <---- the result of the ajax call will be displayed here
</div>
```

In the 'url' attribute we specify the function which will be called when the ajax request triggers. In the 'update' attribute we specified the div where will be displayed the result of calling that function (the image).

Finally, we have to declare the action actionWhichEchoesTheImage(). Let's declare it in the current controller. It would look something like this:

```
    public function actionWhichEchoesTheImage()
   {
      if(isset($_POST['ModelName']['attribute']))
         /*Here goes your code to load the image*/
         echo CHtml::image(//Check the reference to see how to set this function); 
   }
```

Check CHtml::image() here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml/#image-detail

Comment: thanks for replying.what if the dropdown already has an ajax action to it,can I call two separate actions and also update that div and also another dropdown?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but it would require some jQuery code. I have to tell you that, from my point of view, that's entirely another question. You could perhaps post it. It'd be a good one.